# JQuery - Dynamically Changing Pages

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

This is kind of hard to explain but i'll do my best to explain it and maybe someone knows what i'm trying to do.

I have a dashboard.php page and within that page i have a main-interface div that covers 100% width underneath a nav a header.

This dashboard when the user clicks a link changes the content of main-interface div with data from another page for instance search user.

I can load the search user page into the main interface fine but the problem I have is when I click search user it takes me back to the dashboard.php page with the original main-interface content rather than a table of all the users I searched.

I am having trouble telling the jquery that I want it to search for users and populate it back into the main interface page after the search user link was clicked.

Hope some one gets the idea of what im doing and trying to accomplish.

Comment: Your goal makes sense but it's hard to provide direction without seeing some of your code

Comment: without a demo is very difficult to ascertain what you are doing within your code

Answer (score 0):

You could split tasks into client tasks and server tasks.

Client tasks are things that javascript/jQuery will do on the browser.
And server tasks are things that your server will do when requests get in.
This does not mean that the server will need to create full html pages, just send some information to the client bypassing a full page creation.

I often do something like:

```
<script>
    var send = { };
    send[ 'find'  ] = $("input[name='find']").val();
    send[ 'token' ] = $("input[name='token']").val();

    $.post( 'request.php', send, function( data ) {

        $("#name").html( data );

    });
</script>
```

There are some options on the data you will get from the request.php.
You can let request.php create html that you can put into a `<div id="name">`.
Or write client side code that creates HTML from JSON.

Hope it makes sense.